# How to save a graphic in R instead of visualizing it?

Tags: r, heatmap

I a bit of code that produces a matrix. I then generate a heatmap from this matrix using the function:

```
heatmap(d)
```

However, I would like to be able to save this img directly and bypass displaying the graphic, so that I can incorporate this function into a unix-based workflow.

Can someone please show me the snippet of code required to save this image without displaying it on screen? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `jpeg()`, `png()` or `tiff()` to create the file.

```
jpeg(file="filename.jpg")
heatmap(d)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks again Hong! I'll accept after the time limit

Comment: @jake9115 see `?Devices` for more options/details.

Comment: Another question... I was able to get this to work great on my Windows installation, but on my unix terminal I get this error:   Error in X11(paste("jpeg::", quality, ":", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
  unable to start device JPEG
Calls: jpeg
In addition: Warning message:
In jpeg(file = "hen.jpg") : unable to open connection to X11 display ''
Execution halted
I am purposely using png() or jpg() so I can avoid the X11 issues, since I don't want to use X11. Any Ideas for a fix?

Comment: jpeg is probably the worst format for almost any R graphics, try pdf or png instead. The devices available on your machine are described in `capabilities()`